# How can I monitor requested IPs to a specific domain?

Tags: linux, centos, dns, ip

I have an A record in the DNS server which points to my server IP. Noted that I have multiple domain names which points to the same server too.

Now I need to know, which IPs send a request to this specific domain name? `pbx.mywebsite.com`

How can I figure it out?

Comment: can you explain the context to which this applies (web service, ssh, ... ?)

Comment: @tonioc Not sure what you mean exactly, but it's all about a website, so I guess the answer is *web service*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the requests at several points of your infra-structure.

If your intentions are knowing who made the DNS requests, you can configure and activate BIND logs temporarily to log queries requests. At the BIND server, you can also run `dnscap` or `tcpdump`

If you want to know who accessed the site, you can see the web server request logs, or use `tcpdump` at the web server side.

In BIND to activate query logs, the syntax is:

```
logging {

    channel querylog{
        file "/var/log/querylog";
        severity debug 10;
        print-category yes;
        print-time yes;
        print-severity yes;
        };
        category queries { querylog;}; 
     };
};
```

Comment: I got the whole of your answer except the last sentence. What's that code snippet? I hardly think it is a command `:-)` .. So how can I execute it? what language is it? What does it do?

Comment: If you run your own DNS/BIND server for that domain, you include it inside the `options {   }`section for it to log all the queries done in a file, and then you `grep` it for your queries. Otherwise, ignore it.